# Javascript Como comparo 2 array?

Tags: javascript, array

Necesito saber como puedo hacer para comparar el indice de 1 array, con todos los indices de otro array. Acá va un ejemplo:

```
    let array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
    let array2 = ["e", "f", "g", "a"];
```

Teniendo eso, como tendria que hacer para que la `"e"` del `array2` se compare con **TODOS** los indices del `array1` y si no encuentra otra `"e"` siga con la siguiente letra, la `"f"`?

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado?

Comment: Nada, por qué no sé como hacerlo.

Comment: Tu pregunta lleva 3 votos para terminar cerrada, para evitar eso y que el contenido perdure y quede para todos y todas por favor edita y agrega lo que lleves aunque contenga errores

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo mi propuesta, usando `forEach` para recorrer ***array1*** y usando una función para determinar si el elemento enviado existe o no en ***array2*** por medio de `includes`, sí existe lo guardó en ***coincidencias***, quedaría así:

```js
let array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
let array2 = ["a", "b", "g", "a"];
let coincidencias = [];

array1.forEach(comparar);

function comparar(item) {
  if(array2.includes(item) && (coincidencias.includes(item) === false)){
  coincidencias.push(item);
  };
}

console.log(coincidencias);
```

**Actualización**: hice una modificacion por si el elemento ya existe en ***coincidencias*** para que no se guarde nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

Una posibilidad sería:

```
let array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
let array2 = ["e", "f", "g", "a"];

function checkArrays(arr1, arr2){
    //Este bucle recorrerá el arr2 guardando cada letra en la variable letter
    for (letter of arr2) {
        //Aquí compruebo si el arr1 contiene la letra, si es así, la devuelvo directamente
        if(arr1.includes(letter))
            return letter;
    }
}
//Esto devolverá 'a'
alert(checkArrays(array1, array2));
```

Comment: Benito-B si no responde tu no eres tu xdxd

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución sería la siguiente, utilizando la función `find` propia de la clase Array de javascript. Esta metodo recibe una función, que dada la condición retorna el elemento que coincida. [Dejo un enlace con la explicación mas detallada.](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find)

```js
const array1 = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ];
const array2 = [ "a", "d", "e", "f", "c" ];

for (const item of array1) {
    const isInArray2 = array2.find((item2) => {
        return item == item2;
    });
    if (!isInArray2) {
        console.log(`Item: ${item} is not in the array2`);
    }
}
```

Probablemente existan soluciones mas eficientes. Dependiendo de la cantidad de elementos que tenga el array, sería mejor ordenarlo y comparar.

Comment: Te recomiendo que expliques el código que has puesto, tal vez quien lea la pregunta luego no entienda la respuesta. Puedes leer [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para más información

Comment: @Benito-B considero que el código se entiende muy bien, los comentarios estan sobrando. Pero aún así deje la explicación de la función `find`. Igual gracias por la critica.

Comment: @AlexanderYammine como observación, el explicar código siempre será algo que se pida en esta comunidad, por que debes recordar lo que puede ser muy simple y obvio para ti tal vez para otros no, entonces dejar la respuesta explicada siempre es mejor

Comment: No creo que los comentarios sobren, nunca. Especialmente cuando utilizas elementos como lambdas o constantes, returns dentro de lambdas... ese tipo de cosas no suelen ser fáciles de entender para gente que está empezando en esto